# Problem when using position sticky with transform:scale

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky

I'm trying to build a layout.
2 cols. Using flexbox.
I want that the left col will be position sticky. (in case the main content height is high and the user is scrolling down.)

However, the main div also has a fixed width. (i need it for large screens devices)

unfortunately, The transform:scale is causing me a problem. top: 0 does not seems to be 0.

Here is the code (please run in "Full page" mode):

```css
 body{
             background-color: blue;
         }
    
         #fixedBody{
             margin: auto;
            width:980px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            background-color: white;
            transform: scale(1.25);
            transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
         }
    
         aside{
             flex: 0 0 100px;
             position: sticky;
             top: 0px;
             align-self: self-start;
         }
    
         article{
             flex:1;
             text-align:center;
         }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="fixedBody" class="flex-layout">
            <aside>
                <ul>
                    <li>menu</li>
                    <li>menu</li>
                    <li>menu</li>
                    <li>menu</li>
                    <li>menu</li>
                    <li>menu</li>
                    <li>menu</li>
                    <li>menu</li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
            <article>
                <ul>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                    <li>main content</li>
                </ul>
            </article>
        </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Anybody knows how to fix this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: You're scaling the outer wrapper until the aside content leaves the screen to the left.

Comment: the duplicate deals with position:fixed and it's the same case for sticky since sticky is a mix of relative and fixed

Comment: the only way to obtain what you want, is to move the scroll to the scaled container by adding for example `height:100vh;overflow:auto` but IMO using scale is a bad idea here

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks. can u please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: simply try `height:100vh;overflow:auto` to the container where you applied scale